# Persistence on Tinycore 12.0 virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, 64bit, persistence, tinycore

Using Oracle Virtual Box, I have a Tinycore 12.0 virtual machine with a MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 host. I have the most minimal Core version, no GUI, because I was having trouble with mouse tracking and I would only really use the machine for the command line.

The issue I'm having is that I can't get things to "stick" through reboots. When I first booted, nothing stuck, so I looked around and used `tce-ab` to install `tc-install`. I then used `tc-install.sh` to install on the virtual disk I had created in virtualbox (32 GB). I selected `ext4` for the install. I also used the boot options `opt=sda1 home=sda1 tce=sda1`. I installed `vim` to test, and it stuck through reboots.

At this point, I tried adding a file to the home directory. After `touch test` and `sudo reboot`, `test` was gone.

My `/mnt/sda1/tce/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf` file looks like this:

```
DEFAULT corepure64
LABEL corepure64
KERNEL /tce/boot/vmlinuz64
INITRD /tce/boot/corepure64.gz
APPEND quiet user=myname opt=sda1 home=sda1 tce=sda1 norestore
```

The `norestore` comes from https://www.linuxsecrets.com/tinycorelinux-wiki/wiki:backup_hd.html

The boot options I used come from https://www.linuxsecrets.com/tinycorelinux-wiki/wiki:install_hd.html

I have absolutely no attachment to any data on this system, and I'm at a complete loss at what to do.

Edit: On boot, there is an space to specify options manually. If I do this and type `mc home=sda1`, then the home directory persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the same person as the asker.

This is... embarassing. After a bit of rooting around and http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/install.html, I realized I forgot to remove the virtual disc from the optical drive. Everything seems to be working, and I'll leave this question up for anyone who needs it. Oops.